# Cross domain jquery ajax request with custom headers and request body as JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, preflight

I need to create a `JSON` `ajax request` from another domain. after I think I got over the cross domain issues, here is where I stuck:

I need to add my custom "`myCustomHeader`" header - that's easy from a `server`, but seems to be much more complicated from the `client`...

We added them

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: put the results of your header request here,
    url: 'http://server.com/service',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) { 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('myCustomHeader', '1') 
    },
    success: function(data) {    
        alert('success.');
    }
});
```

This generates a `preflight` header with the headers I wanted, without the `values` (`CSV`), but they do not appear in the header of the `request` itself (as  `myCustomHeader=X`)...

Comment: Have you checked that server-side you do return the header Access-Control-Allow-Headers, containing 'myCustomHeader' ?

Comment: Note that you cannot send custom headers when you are using JSONP (in case you do somehow).

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comments - Regarding JBL - No, i'm checking with the IT. Felix - no jsonp, just standard text type from jquery ajax, i belive its ok... thanks!

Comment: jsonp is the only cross domain method (outside of proxies and adobe flash) that I know of. How did you get over cross domain issues without a proxy?

Comment: I just read about CORS, is your server sending the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Comment: Hi Shanimal, we added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the server response and we are able to do that. In the ajax request we use text as the type. Should there be a problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CORS for this purpose.

Example code:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; 

function CrosDom_ajax(url) {
        if (window.XDomainRequest
        && $.browser.msie
        && $.browser.version < 10) {
        xdr = new XDomainRequest();
        if (xdr) {
            xdr.onload = function () {
               alert(xdr.responseText);

            };
            xdr.open("get", url);
            xdr.send();
        }
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function (response) {


                },
                error: function (data) {
                }
            });
         }
    }
```

Also you need to Write the following code in server side, to allow cross domain access

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```